# How to passed numeric value on kubernetes secret

Tags: kubernetes

I want to passed numeric value such as IP address, port, etc. How to do this in kubernetes secret since its using base64 to store to secret?

I've tried to throw raw IP and port to base64 and store it to secret but the application can't read it.

this is my dummy secret

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: db-creds
type: Opaque
data:
  dbHost: base64encoded
  dbPort: base64encoded
```

Comment: Please, check if you encoded your secrets correctly by using ´echo "YOURbase64encodedSecret" | base64 --decode´ command.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've done make sure that the decode of the encoded IP/port are same. But when I tried to login to my app, the app can't read either IP or port.

Comment: Ok, what version of k8s are you using? What application can´t read from the secret? Could you please provide it´s logs and `kubectl get secret db-creds -o yaml` output? Do you use a Volume or env variables to access your secret?